# $_GET variables don't work my ec2 instance using cloudfront aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

On my website, `$_GET` variables for php do not work (undefined index error). For my behavior settings, I have this set:

[image]

Is there another option I have to set?

Comment: Hello! could you state what do you have as the index field of the cloudfront config?

Comment: @LuigiLopez is this for the cloudfront settings  (general), the behavior settings, the origin settings, etc?

Comment: Yes sir. The cloudfront settings

Comment: So would that be the "Default Root Object"? If so, it is set to index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CloudFront settings would not be related at all to you not having $_GET unless it is related to query strings appended at the end.

If thats the case then you need to look either forwarding important keys, or all keys (although this will affect caching performance).

> You can configure CloudFront do one of the following:
>
> - Don't forward query strings to the origin at all. If you don't forward query strings, CloudFront doesn't cache based on query string parameters.
> - Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on all parameters in the query string.
> - Forward query strings to the origin, and cache based on specified parameters in the query string.

Take a further read here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html